# PHP - session_start

Tags: php, session, path, session-cookies, session-variables

I am currently scans on my site to check for **vulnerabilities**.
I only have **one medium error**, in relation to `session_start()`.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
// **PREVENTING SESSION HIJACKING**
// Prevents javascript XSS attacks aimed to steal the session ID
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);

// **PREVENTING SESSION FIXATION**
// Session ID cannot be passed through URLs
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

// Uses a secure connection (HTTPS) if possible
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);

$session_name = session_name();
if (isset($_COOKIE[$session_name]) && empty($_COOKIE[$session_name])) {
    // This happens when someone does "clear cookie" in Firebug; it causes session_start()
    // to trigger a warning. session_start() relies on $_COOKIE[$session_name], thus:
    unset($_COOKIE[$session_name]);
}

session_start();
?>
```

Here is the result of the scan:

> Setting too long or otherwise invalid session values is going to cause
>   the PHP `session_start()`: function to throw an exception that could
>   expose your internal paths.

They use :

> Cookie    PHPSESSID=.

So I come to you today to have a little help with their "error".

Comment: what's your expected outcome?

Comment: Don't take all warnings at face value. That advise is quite wishy-washy, and unsetting the cookie is not going to help anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, however it scared me a little. Logically my site has nothing to fear but this scanner alerted me to this fact